# How, if at all, did Caliban overcome these two?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

At the end of the seventh episode of the third season of *Chilling Adventures of Sabrina*, we see that Caliban was able to, apparently, overcome both Lilith and Lucifer and imprison them in the same sort of prison that Judas Iscariot was originally in.

How did he do this? By all appearances, Caliban is a bit of a lightweight as far as demons go, not even able to put up a fight against Pilate. By contrast, Lucifer seems to be the undisputed top dog in Hell in terms of power, capable of snapping the neck of the one of the Three Kings with a wave of his hand, not to mention being the "Great Satan that no prison can hold." Lilith isn't exactly weak, either: I always got the impression she was roughly the second-strongest in Hell, otherwise Lucifer would hardly trust her with the most important missions, nor would she have been able to rule Hell after his defeat.

So how was Caliban able to overcome and imprison them?